# How to check if one generic type is a subclass of other generic type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

How can we check in Swift that one generic type is inherited from other?

I have this code:

```
class Style<U: Styleable> {
    ...
    init<V: Styleable>(_ style: Style<V>) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to ensure inside this init that it only can be called when `U` is subclass of `V`. I don't know any way to check this at compile time – Swift does not allow (yet, maybe?) to constrain one generic type to be subclass of other. So the only thing I can do is to use some asserts so program is crashed when used in wrong way.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: @MartinR: I gave the wrong example. The real problem I tried to solve was a little bit more difficult. Please check edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I find an answer. It was so close:
`assert(U.self is V.Type)`

Comment: that's a run-time check for a compile time statement.  It works, but too late.